Dealing with cold
I wonder, in everyday life, when I feel really cold outside and I want to rush indoors for warmth, how these ascetics deal with it. I understand coldness is a part of reality and must ideally be experienced when it presents itself with a calm mind.
I'm curious how ascetics, like the Buddha and his followers, manage this since they lived in the forests for extended periods without heating or modern amenities. How is it possible for them not to get sick or die from diseases and cold? More importantly, in the early stages of renunciation, how do they resist the urge to return to civilization?
Sorry, if its a silly question, But I have wondered about it every day these months, without finding an answer yet. Thanks

Monks and nuns should give up the defilements of suffering from cold and heat, by using appropriate clothing and lodging.

And what are the defilements that should be given up by using? Take a
mendicant who, reflecting rationally, makes use of robes: ‘Only for
the sake of warding off cold and heat; for warding off the touch
of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, and reptiles; and for covering up the
private parts.’ ..... Reflecting rationally, they make use of
lodgings: ‘Only for the sake of warding off cold and heat; for
warding off the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, and
reptiles; to shelter from harsh weather and to enjoy retreat.’ .....
For the distressing and feverish defilements that might arise in
someone who lives without using these things do not arise when they
are used. These are called the defilements that should be given up by
using.
AN 6.58 and MN 2


A mendicant might wish: ‘May I receive robes, almsfood, lodgings, and
medicines and supplies for the sick.’ So let them fulfill their
precepts, be committed to inner serenity of the heart, not neglect
absorption, be endowed with discernment, and frequent empty huts.
A mendicant might wish: ‘May the services of those whose robes,
almsfood, lodgings, and medicines and supplies for the sick I enjoy be
very fruitful and beneficial for them.’ So let them fulfill their
precepts, be committed to inner serenity of the heart, not neglect
absorption, be endowed with discernment, and frequent empty huts.
AN 10.71

However, after they have obtained and are using appropriate clothing and lodging, if they still suffer from cold and heat, they should give up these defilements by enduring.

And what are the defilements that should be given up by enduring? Take
a mendicant who, reflecting rationally, endures cold, heat,
hunger, and thirst. They endure the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind,
sun, and reptiles. They endure rude and unwelcome criticism. And they
put up with physical pain — sharp, severe, acute, unpleasant,
disagreeable, and life - threatening. For the distressing and feverish
defilements that might arise in someone who lives without enduring
these things do not arise when they are endured. These are called the
defilements that should be given up by enduring.
AN 6.58 and MN 2


A mendicant might wish: ‘May I endure cold, heat, hunger, and thirst.
May I endure the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, and reptiles.
May I endure rude and unwelcome criticism. And may I put up with
physical pain—sharp, severe, acute, unpleasant, disagreeable, and
life-threatening.’ So let them fulfill their precepts, be committed to
inner serenity of the heart, not neglect absorption, be endowed with
discernment, and frequent empty huts.
AN 10.71

For endurance of cold and heat is considered patient practice.

And what’s the impatient practice? It’s when someone cannot endure
cold, heat, hunger, and thirst. They cannot endure the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, and reptiles. They cannot
endure rude and unwelcome criticism. And they cannot put up with
physical pain—sharp, severe, acute, unpleasant, disagreeable, and
life-threatening. This is called the impatient practice.
And what’s the patient practice? It’s when someone endures cold,
heat, hunger, and thirst. They endure the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, and reptiles. They endure rude and
unwelcome criticism. And they put up with physical pain—sharp, severe,
acute, unpleasant, disagreeable, and life-threatening. This is called
the patient practice.
AN 4.165

Also, the lesser and minor training rules may be adapted if required, based on the Great Standards.
So, if special clothing and heated lodging for very cold weather was not allowed in northern India (where the Buddha resided and taught), it may now be allowed in cold climate regions (such as Canada and Nordic countries) through adaptation of the rules, if decided by the Sangha.
From The Bhikkhus' Rules: A Guide for Laypeople by Ven. Ariyesako:

Modernization? The Great Standards
More than two and a half thousand
years have passed since the Vinaya rules were originally set down by
the Buddha, and many things have markedly changed since then. Should
the rules be modernized and brought up to date? How can this be done?
Already during His lifetime, the Buddha made special allowances for
different regions (or desa) outside the 'Middle Country' of North
India — where He lived and taught. These dealt with both the workings
of the Community — for example, a smaller quorum for ordination is
allowed in distant parts where there are fewer monks — and practical
measures, such as special dispensation for footwear and bathing. (See
EV,II,p.173) So there is a precedent for adapting to conditions, but
this does not mean the abolishing of any rules [see End Note 6].
The Lord Buddha also left us a set of principles that can still be
used as a standard to judge new circumstances.[35] These are known as
'The Great Standards.' Properly used they should protect against a
wholesale dilution of the Rule.[36]
This is how the Great Standards are formulated:

"Bhikkhus, whatever I have not objected to, saying, 'This is not
allowable,' if it fits in with what is not allowable, if it goes
against what is allowable, that is not allowable for you.
"Whatever I have not objected to, saying, 'This is not allowable,' if
it fits in with what is allowable, if it goes against what is not
allowable, that is allowable for you.
"And whatever I have not permitted, saying, 'This is allowable,' if it
fits in with what is not allowable, if it goes against what is
allowable, that is not allowable for you.
"And whatever I have not permitted, saying, 'This is allowable,' if it
fits in with what is allowable, if it goes against what is not
allowable, that is allowable for you." (BMC p.27; see also EV, II,
p170)

Treated with care, these Great Standards should enable bhikkhus to
live according to the Vinaya Rule in, for example, isolated
communities in non-Buddhist countries with non-tropical climates. They
form a touchstone for modern conditions and substances.


+1 I hope readers will learn to appreciate this sensible and rational answer. To toughen it out regardless of cold, hot and whatever weather elements sounds like asceticism esp. if one has no consideration for one's physique and health conditions or the allowances permitted in the Vinaya. The Vinaya was not set down for training ascetics but to support the path to Enlightenment. It would not be the Middle Way otherwise. We guard our bodies from illnesses by being sensible, not by toughing it out like ascetics.

but how are the defilement of suffering caused by cold and heat known?

@blue_ego It's mental aversion (dosa) against the painful feeling (dukkha vedana) of cold or heat.

@blue_ego I agreed with ruben2020, I don't think extreme temperatures are the root cause of defilements. I thought you meant how to deal with the sufferings caused by extreme heat and cold. Otherwise, you may want to post a question?

People volunteer for things like that because they believe the gain will be worth more than the pain. And some people enjoy the pain in a way, or get satisfaction from seeing how much they can endure, how tough they are. And importantly, they know they can end it at any time, no one is forcing them to run the whole marathon, etc. It seems doing things voluntarily makes it more tolerable than if you don't have a choice.
I think the ascetic impulse is the idea that you can overcome suffering by making yourself suffer more, a sort of exposure therapy, desensitization, or mind over matter ("I don't mind, so it don't matter"). The Buddha tried extreme self mortification and found it's unsatisfactory. Monks are supposed to be content with any old cloth, food, shelter (AN 4.28), and you can get used to a lot of things, and gradually get tougher, but there's only so much you can take, so they're allowed to eat every day, live in shelter, wear enough clothes, get medical treatment, etc. MN 90 says for proper exertion, you should be neither too hot or cold. Practical and not extreme.
But in the early days, finding out how tough it still is, you'd have to rely on faith to keep you going, which you'd already have a huge amount of if you're willing to ordain in the first place. After that, I imagine they could treat the hardship as an opportunity to practice, e.g. letting go of or being detached from desire and aversion, trying to embody tolerance, endurance, patience; examining how sense contact creates the experience of cold and how the mind reacts to it.

There is the case where a monk, reflecting appropriately, uses the robe simply to counteract cold, to counteract heat, to counteract the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, & reptiles; simply for the purpose of covering the parts of the body that cause shame. ... he uses lodging simply to counteract cold... The fermentations, vexation, or fever that would arise if he were not to use these things [in this way] do not arise for him when he uses them [in this way]. ...
And what are the fermentations to be abandoned by tolerating? There is the case where a monk, reflecting appropriately, endures. He tolerates cold, heat, hunger, & thirst; the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, & reptiles... -MN 2
 
A priest has no real home. He can't settle anywhere. He sleeps in the open fields or in the hills. For him, there's only hardship and hunger. No one is waiting for him where he goes. There's never a moment of relief from his hard life. With
only his ordinary robes and no extra clothing, he has no way to keep himself warm in cold weather. No, I don't think anything can begin to compare with the privations a priest experiences. Still, he carries on his practice, taxing his body severely, and for one reason: because he wants to discover the wonderful
bliss of the Buddha-mind. When his practice is completed, he teaches others, and he receives from them donations and benefits of various kinds. His years of painful practice are then all transformed into the Dharma, and he lives in the wonderful knowledge of the unborn Buddha-mind. -Bankei


Meditation Master Goso Hōen [] once said:
When my Master’s Master first took up residence on Mount
Yōgi, the rafters of the old buildings were in ruins and the damage
from wind and rain was extensive. It was midwinter at the time. The
temple halls throughout the monastery had long been damaged. The
Monks’ Hall was especially dilapidated. The snow kept drifting in,
and it so filled the floors that there was nowhere for the monks to sit.
Veteran monks, their hair white with age, were sweeping the snow off
everything, including themselves, and shaggy eyebrowed monks of
venerable years looked as though those brows were knitted with
apprehension. The monks of the community were unable to do their
seated meditation tranquilly. ... We hunched up our necks and grumbled in the gloom. But then, with a change of heart, we recalled the old ones who had resided under trees.
...
Calmly imagine the ceaseless practice that was happening on Mount Isan
long ago. What I mean by ‘imagine’ means thinking about how it would be for us
today if we were residing on Mount Isan. ... On the snowy nights in the dead of
winter, the birds and beasts must have been scarce indeed, and how much less
would there have been smoke from man-made fires to acknowledge human
existence! It was a way of living that could not have been tolerated, were it not for the Master’s ceaseless practice in which he made light of his life whilst stressing the Dharma. He was in no hurry to cut down the undergrowth, nor did he engage in cutting down trees to clear the land for building. He just continued his ceaseless practice and simply did his utmost to practice the Way. What a pity that an authentic Ancestor who had Transmitted, and kept to, the True Dharma came to
undergo such hardships in such precipitous mountains! It is said that Mount Isan
had many ponds and running water, so there must have been thick ice and dense
banks of fog. Most people could not have tolerated such a secluded life,
nevertheless Isan transformed it into the Buddha’s Way and explored Its innermost
purpose. -Dogen's Shobogenzo


The answer is simple.Once you realize the gravity of the situation and you become monk , you go through the cold or heat or whatever the weather conditions are. Essentially you do not crave for civilisation or clothes or food. You take whatever is given as told by Buddha in the Noble Eight Fold path as Right Livelihood.
If food is given you take the food. If clothes are given you take the clothes. If shelter is given you take the shelter but you do not crave for it.As a monk, you have to be in meditative state all the time. For example - when it feels cold you remind yourself that there is a feeling of cold, and like all feelings this too has origin and that which has origin will come to an end. This feeling will pass. You should be alert about whatever feelings are coming to you. It is a tough path and Dhamma should be understood properly and one should be aware of it all the time. Once you go through the cold or heat or rain then over a period of time you become tolerant towards it. In any case you should not leave Dhamma.

There is a good point here that enduring the cold over time allows one to become accustomed to in.

@Remyla I helped a kid make a snowman a few weeks ago, I'd stepped outside to check the weather, with no sleeves and no gloves -- he asked me, "Isn't it cold?", and I replied, "Well of course it's cold!" But I'm Canadian, I figure I can tell the difference between superficial/transient cold and like, frostbite or hypothermia.

@blue_ego Of course. The reason can not remain hidden forever. Buddhism is based on experience.

@ChrisW i think beauty helps too...

In most cases I would expect that the ascetic must deal primarily with the function of mind, so in the case of dealing with the cold, there is obviously a physical aspect of physical feeling one experiences from temperature but cold itself is just a sensory experience one can endure with patience. It is the suffering it causes, a mental factor, that the person needs to primarily deal with. Reminding themselves of the nature of samasara and the 3 marks of existence, that cold is indeed an unpleasant (also impermanent) sensation and that it is the clinging to the sensation that causes suffering, i.e the 7th and 8th dependant related links.
That being said on a more practical level. While a (traditional) ordained person is not allowed to own more than robes and a bowl, sticks, wood, tinder, kindling are not owned by anyone and enduring hardship like cold for the sake of it is an extreme, extreme asceticism. So one would expect even the sangha in the Buddhas age did in fact take sticks off the ground, rub sticks together and make fire.
Plus also keep in mind that ancient Nepal/India was nowhere near as cold as say modern day northern Europe. So if you were a European ascetic in modern times, you would need more tools and ability to make fire to literally survive, or it would be testament to suicide via negligence of oneself, again an extreme. Meaning to collect firewood and keep them dry in anticipation for the extreme weather.
Remember the original sangha retreated to caves to wade out the monsoon season. In Europe we don't have monsoons, we have extreme cold. So one would expect the same precautions of retreating to a cave (and collecting firewood) is what is needed to endure extreme cold, just like Buddha and the sangha did to endure extreme rain.
Even the dhutanghas, the ascetic practices praised by the Buddha have no mention of "enduring weather for the sake of enduring"
Then to add, in Tibet, obviously even more cold that northern Europe, specifically the vajrayana teachings, some have mastered the practice of tummo, a meditation practice gaining the ability to regulate the inner heat of the body. Where these teachings originated from I do not know, most likely post Buddhas life but it would lead one to expect such things were known and maybe practised as a direct antidote to extreme cold within the Buddhas lifetime. just of course Buddhas teachings are document only relating to the Dharma, not for yogic practises that are not directly leading to liberation.
As for resisting the urge to return to society. Well one abandons the householder lifestyle because of seeing how fruitless it is. They would have only needed to basic contemplate what life was like before going forth into the homeless life to realize that it is a folly to think reverting back to a householder life will sort the real problems out. A householder and an ascetic both get cold in the winter regardless. Plus they would still have had to re-enter society for alms round regardless.
I personally think in modern time Europe one would genuinely need support of lay people to survive asceticism like the original sangha did to endure the cold. Be it a coat, sleeping bag, windbreaking equipment, tent/coat etc or actual shelter in their home. Let alone food. One would probably get frostbite and die walking barefoot and living with only robes and a bowl like the original sangha did in modern northern Europe weather.

I used Europe as my basis of the place of dealing with cold weather though it is interchangeable with any northern hemisphere areas that deal with extreme cold. I think it would be impossible to live and survive the weather like the original sangha did in modern places like canada, alaska, siberia.  I also find it quite funny that modern (western) theravada sects "celebrate" vasak, the rains retreat like the original sangha and have not adopted the retreat time of the year to their surroundings.

I get your general point. Dhutangas have mentioned it though. One of those 13 practices is to not take shelter of roof..which is equivalent to bearing different weathers (?)
Great answer overall, thanks!

Here's the modern climate for Varanasi:



https://weatherspark.com/y/110718/Average-Weather-in-Varanasi-Uttar-Pradesh-India-Year-Round

So the "low" temperature is 50F i.e. 10C.
I call that a "double-digit temperature" -- because that's 10 or above -- at that temperature I wear a T-shirt outside (and so it seems humanly possible to me).
I suppose that monks have robes and so on and needn't expose their skin. You can also stay a lot warmer with some muscular exercise -- maybe walking sometimes during the night. Also having an "inner robe" I presume will help with insulation, i.e. to protect the core.
In other climates they change the monastic rules slightly -- e.g I believe that monks wear shoes or boots outside during Canadian winters.

well from personal experience in that area, I can say it gets lowest around 35-40F. Also, areas just in north of that, for example Nepal where the Buddha originated from, are much colder.
Moreover for us it is different, coz we remain indoors most of the time. But if we were to live outside, even in 50F, it would be much harder. For eg. I can take out trash in a Tshirt when it is 20F...because it is just for a minute...but I don't think i can survive a month like that.
